# Folder ACLs and SSH client unable to access folder (Permission denied)

Tags: ssh, fedora, access-control-list

The directory `/run/media/user/disc` is a directory that is on a SSH server (Fedora 25). Its group is sftponly. I am trying to access to that directory through SSH using a user that is part of sftponly group. Unfortunately I cannot access (read) to such directory (Permission denied). The access control list looks good to me, but there is still some problem:

```
# getfacl /run/media/user/disc
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: run/media/user/disc
# owner: root
# group: sftponly
user::rwx
group::rwx
group:sftponly:r-x
mask::rwx
other::rwx
```

Any idea?  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the parent directories to see if either the user or `sftponly` group have the correct permissions to traverse the directory hierarchy. You can use `namei -ml /run/media/user/disc` as a quick permissions overview.

If that doesn't yield the info you need, you can use `getfacl` on each parent directory to discover if there is a perms issue. Failing that, you should check `/var/log/secure` for clues relating to the failure.

edit: also, if you have only just added the user to the group, make sure you log out and back in again for the changes to take effect.